# Neo4J avoid duplicates on cyclic graph

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph of `PERSON`, `PERSON` can be `FRIEND`s with `PERSON` and can `OWN` `OBJECT` for example:

```
a-FRIEND-b
a-FRIEND-c
b-FRIEND-c
c-OWN-"car"
```

I want to allow someone who need something to find a friend or a friends of a friend which own this something, so I use:

```
MATCH (me:PERSON)-[:FRIEND*1..2]-(p:PERSON)-[o:OWN]->(obj:OBJECT)
WHERE me.id = {userId}
RETURN p
```

But if "a" want "car" I get "c" twice because I can get there in two ways:

```
a-FRIEND-c-OWN-"car"
a-FRIEND-b-FRIEND-c-OWN-"car"
```

How can I make sure I only get "c" once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the [DISTINCT](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-return.html#return-unique-results) modifier to your return statement:

```
MATCH (me:PERSON)-[:FRIEND*1..2]-(p:PERSON)-[o:OWN]->(obj:OBJECT) 
WHERE me.id = {userId} 
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

Comment: Alternatively you might `RETURN p, count(*)` to give an indication of how many paths there are, which might indicate a strength

Comment: And you can embed the id check ;-) ... `MATCH (me:PERSON {id: {userId}}) ...`